# Zooming in on inline SVGs (in webkit)

Tags: html, css, svg

When I zoomed in on an XHTML document containing an SVG, it works correctly in FF and Opera, but in Safari and Chrome the width of svg document is changed by zooming in and out(increased and decreased), Is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

in the top of your code you have used % and px together in width, which should be changed only to percent

```
<span style="border:solid red 1px;display: block; width:100%px;">
```

to

```
<span style="border:solid red 1px;display: block; width:100%;">
```

not sure if that's your problem here but it should be changed